# How can I ignore empty log messages?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I use sanic framework.

I add log module and saw strange logs like this:

```
[2023-05-02 19:25:40 +0900] - (sanic.access)[INFO][127.0.0.1:34844]: GET http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/ta?idtype=1  200 7559
[2023-05-02 19:25:40,969] [INFO] 
[2023-05-02 19:25:40 +0900] - (sanic.access)[INFO][127.0.0.1:34846]: GET http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/sa?idtype=1  200 84895
[2023-05-02 19:25:43,857] [INFO] 
[2023-05-02 19:25:43 +0900] - (sanic.access)[INFO][127.0.0.1:34846]: GET http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/to?type=I&idtype=2  200 26729
[2023-05-02 19:25:43 +0900] - (sanic.access)[INFO][127.0.0.1:34842]: GET http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/ta?idtype=2  200 6233
[2023-05-02 19:25:43,870] [INFO] 
[2023-05-02 19:25:43,877] [INFO]
```

I never wrote empty logs, so I check call stacks.

lower is part of call stack.

```
[13] -   File "/home/deploy/utils/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sanic/response.py", line 122, in send
    await self.stream.send(data, end_stream=end_stream)

[14] -   File "http1_response_header", line 68, in http1_response_header
    HEADER_CEILING = 16_384

[15] -   File "/home/deploy/utils/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sanic/http.py", line 477, in log_response
    access_logger.info("", extra=extra)

[16] -   File "/home/deploy/utils/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1383, in info
    self._log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs)

[17] -   File "/home/deploy/utils/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1519, in _log
    self.handle(record)
```

I think, sanic prints empty logs (I can't understand why).

I want to ignore empty logs.
lower is my logger initialize code. How can I do it?

```
def initialize_logger():
    class StreamLogFormatter(logging.Formatter):
        format_type = "[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s"

        def format(self, record):
            trace(record.msg)
            formatter = logging.Formatter(self.format_type)
            return formatter.format(record)

    logger = logging.getLogger()

    # remove default handler
    logger.handlers = []

    # console log
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    console_handler.setFormatter(StreamLogFormatter())
    logger.addHandler(console_handler)

    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    return logger
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Handler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#handler-objects)s can [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.filter) records according to the filters they have defined. If for whatever reason your program sends empty logs, you can filter those out by adding a simple filter:

```py
console_handler.addFilter(lambda record: record.msg.strip() != '')
```

A short MRE to demonstrate:

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.addFilter(lambda record: record.msg.strip() != '')
logger.addHandler(console_handler)

logger.info("msg1")
logger.info("   ")
logger.info("msg2")
```

Will only print:

```
msg1
msg2
```

---

If you have multiple `Handler`s and want them all to have that behavior - `Logger` objects also have a [`addFilter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.addFilter) method so the same filter can be applied directly on the `logger`.

Comment: it's perfectly what i want! thanks!!
however, addFilter to logger is work in test code, but 'sanic' project doesn't.
i suspect sanic overwrite filter, it can be possible?

Comment: I admit that I'm not familiar with sanic and don't know how it handles the logging. I was trying to give a general answer. I find it hard to believe it would overwrite the filters but again, don't know it. Maybe try to add the filter after any initialization you do to sanic. Let it configure the logger and only then add the filter